# How to pass array from public method to action event method

Tags: java, arrays, methods, parameter-passing, actionevent

Here is the public method:

```
public void Hangman() {
    Random ran = new Random();
    int num = ran.nextInt(8);
    char[] currentword = wordlist(num);
    exes(currentword.length);
    }
```

Here is the action event method:

```
 private void btntryActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    char[] v = {'c', 'e', 'n', 't', 'i', 'p', 'e', 'd', 'e'};
```

currentword is an array. I want to pass this array to the action event method (btntryActionPerformed) so that I can have something like this:

```
 private void btntryActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    char[] v = currentword;
```

In the first code snippet what happens is that a random number is generated and I already have a method with several arrays in it (not shown here). It uses a switch case  statement to randomly select an array and assign it to the array currentword (also not shown here). I want to then send this array (currentword) to the action event method and assign it to the array "v". All arrays are char.

How can I do this?

Comment: place: char[] currentword = {}; to the constructor of your class so that it can be used by all methods within the class. Then in the Hangman() method use:  currentword = wordlist(num);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use class(instance) level variable in which class action event method is defined, to pass that array in action event method.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have additional arguments to your listener methods while overriding those methods in your class.

But you can have a char array as the class member and access the same in your listener method.